# How to check CPU type to source from Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, zsh, apple-m1

I use both M1 and Intel MBP. They do share the same `.zshrc` from my [dotfiles](https://github.com/ogirginc/dotfiles/blob/main/zshrc). I want to source different files depending on CPU type. For example:

On M1, only these files should be sourced:

```
source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

On Intel , only these files should be sourced:

```
source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` automatically sets `CPUTYPE` on startup, so you can use that instead of running `sysctl`.

```
declare -A foo
foo[x86_64]=/usr/local/
foo[arm64]=/opt/homebrew

source $foo[$CPUTYPE]/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggetions.zsh
source $foo[$CPUTYPE]/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

Note that in some sense, you are just using the CPU type as a proxy for a specific machine. (You could just as easily have two different Intel machines with different locations for the ZSH configuration files.) A better solution might be to use `$HOST` instead of `$CPUTYPE` to identify machine-specific options.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I now use @chepner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68469807/4565485).

---

<strike>I have [ended up](https://github.com/ogirginc/dotfiles/commit/12345e978cd473ad2b96e70c147c7b8b761d3d45) with a simple if statement:</strike>

```sh
local cpu_name=$(sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string)

if [ $cpu_name = "Apple M1" ]; then
  source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
  source /opt/homebrew/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
else
  source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
  source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
fi
```